# How to draw real-time moving circle in Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make 2D collision simulation in Python.

I made a circle on the figure to use as an object, and I wanted to move it in real-time without the figure window closed.

I found this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.cos(x)

fig = plt.figure()

for p in range(50):
    p=3
    updated_x=x+p
    updated_y=np.cos(x)
    plt.plot(updated_x,updated_y)
    plt.draw()  
    x=updated_x
    y=updated_y
    plt.pause(0.2)
    fig.clear()
```

and I tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

fig = plt.figure()
board = plt.axes(xlim = (0, 200), ylim = (0, 100))

x = 10
y = 10
r = 10

for p in range(10):
    circle = plt.Circle((x, y), body.r, fc='w', ec='b')
    board.add_patch(circle)

    plt.annotate("", xytext=(x, y), xy=(x+10, y+10), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='r', edgecolor='r', headwidth=6, headlength=6, width=0.1))

    plt.draw()  
    plt.pause(0.2)
    fig.clear()

    x += 10
    y += 10
```

I wanted to draw only the present circle and delete the previous one.

But it didn't worked, and I can't understand why `fig.clear()` in the first code didn't really clear it.

Please help me...

Comment: You should take a look at matplotlib.animation. It allows you to animate plot through time.

Comment: But I can't apply it to me. There're just example using `plt.plot`

Comment: I couldn't get it to erase the previous animation, but I was able to create a type that keeps the previous animation. Do I need this as an answer? I will answer if it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was with `fig.clear()`. If you just remove the circle and the annotation from the plot you get an animation.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, animation as an
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
board = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 200), ylim=(0, 100))

x = 10
y = 10
r = 10

for p in range(10):
    circle = plt.Circle((x, y), r, fc='w', ec='b')
    board.add_patch(circle)

    annotation = plt.annotate("", xytext=(x, y), xy=(x+10, y+10), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='r', edgecolor='r', headwidth=6, headlength=6, width=0.1))

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.2)
    circle.remove()
    annotation.remove()
    x += 10
    y += 10

plt.show()
```